Action of a 1-Form in $\Omega^{1}(M, End(E))$ on a Section of a Vector Bundle
Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle over a Riemannian manifold. Consider $\nabla$ and $\nabla'$ two connections over $E$. We can affirm that the difference between these connections, $\nabla - \nabla'$, is an element of $\Omega^{1}(M, \text{End}(E))$. If we consider the associated principal bundle $\text{Gl}(E)$, we can translate this difference from the vector bundle to the principal bundle. With this, we can treat this difference as an element of $\Omega^{1}(\text{Gl}(E), \mathcal{g})^{\text{Ad}}$, where $\text{Ad}$ is the adjoint representation of the group $G$. Therefore, the difference in the associated principal bundle is horizontal and adjoint-invariant.
My question: Consider $u$ a section of the bundle $E$, that is, $u \in \Gamma(E)$, and $A \in \Omega^{1}(M, \text{End}(E))$. Under what conditions can I affirm that $Au = 0$? I would like to understand the action of $A$ on a section of the bundle. I think this can be seen in the principal bundle, but I don't know how.

I am going to do this in great generality. Let $P$ be a principal $G$ bundle over $M$, and $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ a representation of $G$ on a vector space $V$. We construct the associated bundle $E=P\times_{\rho} V$ by defining points $P\times_{\rho} V$ to be the quotient $P\times V/\sim$ where $\sim$ is equivalence relation $(p,v)\sim (p\cdot g, \rho(g)^{-1}v)$.
Note that the isomorphism $A\in \Omega^1(M,\operatorname{End}(E))$ with a \begin{align}
\Omega^k_{\text{hor}}(GL(e),\mathfrak g)^{\text{Ad}}\longrightarrow \Omega^k(M,\operatorname{Ad}(P))
\end{align}
is given by $\omega\mapsto \omega'$, where $\omega'$ is pointwise defined by:
$$\omega'_x(X_1,\dots, X_k)=[p,\omega_p(Y_1,\dots, Y_k)$$
for any $p\in \pi^{-1}(x)$, and $Y_i\in T_pP$ satisfying $D_p\pi Y_i=X_i$.
Let $u\in \Gamma(E)$, and $A\in \Omega^1(M,\operatorname{Ad}(P))$; we want to define a section $Au\in\Omega^1(M,E)$. Well, we know that for some $\omega\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak g)$ that at each point:
\begin{align}
A_x(X)=[p,\omega(Y)]
\end{align}
and moreover that for all $x\in M$, $u_x=[p,v]$ for some $p\in \pi^{-1}(x)$, and $v\in V$. We define $Au$ pointwise by:
$$(Au)_x(X)=[p,\rho_*(\omega_p(Y))v]$$
We need to check that this well defined. This is obviously independent of our choice of $Y$, so it we need to show that this independent of our choice of $p$. We have that:
$$(Au)_{x}(X)=[p\cdot g, \rho_*(\omega_{p\cdot g}(Z))\rho(g^{-1})v]$$
where $Z=R_{g*}Y$ lies in $T_{p\cdot g}P$.
\begin{align}
(Au)_{x}(X)=&[p\cdot g, \rho_*(\omega_{p\cdot g}(R_{g*}Y)\rho(g^{-1})v]\\
=&[p\cdot g,\rho_*((R_{g^*}\omega)_p(Y)\rho(g^{-1})v]\\
=&[p\cdot g,\rho_*(\operatorname{Ad}_{g^{-1}}\circ \omega_p(Y))\rho(g^{-1})v]\\
=&[p\cdot g,\rho(g^{-1})\rho_*(\omega_p(Y))v]\\
=&[p,\rho_*(\omega_p(Y)v]
\end{align}
so $(Au)_x$ is well defined. This is then obviously smooth by taking local sections.
Translating this in terms of a local frame for $E$ and $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$, let $s:U\rightarrow P$ be a local section, then we if $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, and $\{T_a\}$ is a basis for $\mathfrak g$, we obtain local frames by:
$$f_i=[s,e_i]\qquad\text{and}\qquad B_a=[s,T_a]$$
then locally:
\begin{align}
(A|_U(X))_x=[s(x),\omega_{s(x)}(s_*X)]\Rightarrow A|_U=[s,s^*\omega]
\end{align}
We can write $s^*\omega=A^a_j dx^j\otimes T_a$, so that:
$$A|_U=[s,A^a_jdx^j\otimes T_a]$$
Similarly, we have that for some smooth function $\phi:U\rightarrow V$:
$$u(x)=[s(x),\phi(x)]=[s(x),u^i(x)e_i]$$
where $u^i:U\rightarrow \mathbb R$. It follows that $u=[s,u^i e_i]$. Putting this all together we find that $A\cdot u|_U$ is given by:
\begin{align}
A\cdot u|_U=&[s,u^i\rho_*(A^a_jdx^j\otimes T_a)e_i]\\
=&[s,u^iA^a_jdx^j\otimes\rho_*(T_a)e_i]
\end{align}
Now note that this is zero if and only if
$$u^iA^a_jdx^j\otimes\rho_*(T_a)e_i=0$$
and that this calculation is essentially what you are doing when working with a local frame.
So if $A\in \Omega^1(M,\operatorname{Ad}(P))$, and $u\in \Gamma(E)$, then I can expand everything out in my local frames, I have that $\rho_*(A|_U)= A_{jk}^idx^j\otimes f_i\otimes f^k$ (where we have tacitly identified $\rho_*(T_a)$ with a matrix acting on a basis of $V$, so this element lies in the endomorphism bundle), and $u=u^lf_l$, hence:
\begin{align}
A\cdot u|_U=&A_{jk}^iu^ldx^j\otimes f_i\otimes f^k(f_l)\\
=&dx^j\otimes (A_{jk}^iu^kf_i)
\end{align}
So this is only zero if $A_{jk}^iu^kf_i=0\in \Gamma(E|_U)$. Essentially, this means that if you expand $A$ as a the tensor product $dx^j\otimes A_j$, where each $A_j$ is a matrix acting on $\Gamma(E|_U)$, $u$ lies in the kernel of this endomorphism.
Edit:
In particular, if you want to identify $A$ globally with a decomposition $\omega^i\otimes \phi_i$, where $\phi_i\in \Gamma(\operatorname{End}(E))$, then $Au=\omega^i\otimes \phi_i(u)$, which is zero if and only if all $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, the section $\omega^i(X)\phi_i(u)\in \Gamma(E)$ is zero.

If you consider $\Omega^{1}(M,End(E)) \cong \Omega^{1}(M)\otimes \Gamma(End(E))$, we can write $A= \theta \otimes T$. Thus, $Au = 0$ iff $(\theta \otimes T)u = 0$. Thus, we can affirm that $u$ belong kernel of $T$. It is correct?I would like to obtain a condition to bundle

@FigueiredoMartinz You can't write necessarily write $A$ as $\theta\otimes T$, only as a linear combination  of that form, and you can't break this down into a global frame because such a frame need not exist. In particular, you need locally that $A^i_{jk}u^k=0$ for each $j$ and $i$.
